# IF-Like Conditionals without ELSE in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to use simple IF-like modification of the content of a variable in Terraform?

For example:

```
resource "null_resource" "validation_stg_l" {
  count = "${length(local.dvo)}"

  triggers {
    dvo_stg = "${ contains( split(",", var.hosted_zones_stg), replace(lookup(local.dvo[count.index], "domain_name"), "*.", "") ) ? local.dvo[count.index] : ///without this part\\\ }"
  }
}
```

So that you can modify the actual content of the variable and in this way leaving only the desired content?

The above example is only and just an idea for achieving the goal which is not applicable - the conditional operator cannot be used with map values (which should change in Terraform ver. 0.12 in a few months).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be good enough:

```
data "template_file" "validation_stg_l" {
  count    = "${length(local.dvo)}"
  template = "${contains( split(",", var.hosted_zones_stg), replace(lookup(local.dvo[count.index], "domain_name"), "*.", "") ) ? count.index : 111}"
}

locals {
  tf_validation_stg_l_indxd = "${compact( split(",", replace(join(",", data.template_file.validation_stg_l.*.rendered), "111", "") ) )}"
}
```

And the result of the `local` variable can be used in the "`triggers`" of a "`null_resource`" using a map in map code like:

```
local.dvo[local.tf_validation_stg_l_indxd[count.index]]
```

The map values will need to be processed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in thinking you are trying to conditionally set a trigger on some of the indexed instances of `null_resource`, based on whether their domain names are in a list?

If my understanding of https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html is correct, you can use any constant string in the false part of your condition to disable the trigger. The empty string would be as good as any.

The documentation says the `trigger` section is

> A map of arbitrary strings that, when changed, will force the null resource to be replaced, re-running any associated provisioners.

In your case, if you don't want a particular indexed resource to be replaced ever, just use a string that can't change.

One other thing. `dvo_stg` is expected to be a string, but you are try to assign it `local.dvo[count.index]`, which is a used as a map elsewhere. Is that right?

Comment: (1) Yes, you're correct - that's exactly what I'm trying to do - but only because I haven't found another way of "looping" the content of a variable. (2) Yes, it's a map - and not a simple string which I think - is a problem, right? I was thinking to try with a data construct "template_file", not sure whether it will be much better.

Comment: In the end, the conditional operator cannot be used with map values - which is yet another limitation for achieving the goal.